# Overwrite file using append mode for fopen

Tags: c, file, fopen, overwrite

I am using `fopen` to write to a binary file and using the `cstdio (stdio.h)` library due to legacy code and it must be cross-platform compatible with Windows and Linux.

For the prototype, `FILE * fopen ( const char * filename, const char * mode );`, I am using `const char * mode = "ab"`, which will append to a binary file. Writing operations append data at the end of the file. The file is created if it does not exist.

I have N number of input files where I process data from and write to one output file for each type, where I have M types. I process one input file and write the data to each corresponding output file. I then will close that ith input file and open (i + 1)th, and repeat the process by appending the data from the input file to the output files.

**If an output file exists at the beginning on the executable, I want it deleted. If it exists and I don't delete it, then when I use the `"wb"` mode, then it will just append data to the output file, which will result in duplication I don't want.** I am open to a boost solution and I like to maintain standards best as possible (i.e avoid POSIX if possible)

[fopen C++ reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fopen/)

Comment: hold on, do you or don't you want it to overwrite? do you want it to append what's there? please be more clear on what you'd like it to do in the "already exists" and "doesn't already exist" cases...

Comment: Try to clarify your goal more clearly, I can't really tell from your post and code if you want to overwrite (delete) existing files or avoid this. Also, your code doesn't make much sense, because opening an existing file in write mode will delete it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way

```
char* infile[N] = //input names
char* outfile[M] = //output names

int i, j;
for (i = 0; i < N; i++){
  //process input
  char* mode = "ab";
  if (i == 0) mode = "wb";
  for (j = 0; j < M; j++){
    FILE* f = fopen(outfile[j], mode);
    //write to file
    fclose(f);
  }
}
```

The "w" mode should overwrite the file. It is "a" mode that will avoid deleting a file that already exists.

EDIT: You can also `remove (const char * filename)` if you want to delete the files at the beginning of execution. If that's the case then you never have to use the "wb" mode.

Answer (score 4):

One possibility would be to use `open` (`_open` for Windows) to create the appropriate file handle and then use `fdopen` (`_fdopen` for Windows) to create a stdio handle out of it.  You will need some preprocessor magic to handle the fact that the names are not exactly the same in Linux and Windows:

```
// Allow us to use Posix compatible names on Windows
#ifdef WINDOWS
#define open      _open
#define O_CREAT   _O_CREAT
#define O_TRUNC   _O_TRUNC
#define O_APEND   _O_APPEND
#define S_IREAD   _S_IREAD
#define S_IWRITE  _S_IWRITE
#define fdopen    _fdopen
#endif

int fd = open(filename, O_CREAT | O_TRUNC | O_APPEND, S_IREAD | S_IWRITE);
FILE *fp = fdopen(fd, "a");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to overwrite rather than append, why not just use the mode "wb"? "w" overwrites the file when writing.

Comment: Perhaps he wants to destroy the original data but then be in append mode so even if the code fseek's, any writes will still go to end.

Comment: @Klatchko...Hit the nail on the head